# Is it safe to rename the keys of an object while iterating them?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm renaming the keys of an object while iterating them:

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(function(oldKey) {
    var newKey = someFunc(oldKey);
    if (newKey !== oldKey) {
        object[newKey] = object[oldKey];
        delete object[oldKey];
    }
}
```

And I would like to know if this method is safe.

In other words, can I be sure that my code will never iterate a key which has been renamed in a previous iteration?

Comment: This question doesn't have to do with the DOM, but I thought I would clear something up that a now deleted answer said. It incorrectly stated that `querySelectorAll` returns a live list. There are both live and static versions of `NodeList`, `querySelectorAll` actually returns a static (non-live) node list. Some of the older DOM interfaces like `Node.childNodes` return a live `NodeList`, likewise some older interfaces like `getElementsByTagName` return a `HTMLCollection`, which is always live. If the documentation says that it returns an `Array` (like `Object.keys does), that data is non-live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you aren't safe. You're mutating the object live, based on an array that is not live. If you happen to cross a new name with an old (rename a to b, but b already exists and haven't been reached yet) you're going to have a bad time.

You will not come across keys you've already seen, but you have no way to know whether the `newKey` is not already found in the object.

There are workarounds, the situation is similar to `.splice()`ing an array (removing elements) while you iterate it, and the simple workaround is to iterate backwards, so that you always already pass the altered keys. (Or in your case, checking with the `in` operator)

You're much better, however, creating and returning a new object:

```
const newObj = Object.keys(object).reduce(function(result, oldKey) {
    var newKey = someFunc(oldKey);
    return { ...result, [newKey]: object[oldKey] };
}, {});
```

You get a lot of things for free when you treat all of your data structures as immutables (and more specifically, when the keys never change)

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I know for sure that I am never generating a key which already exists? It is not guaranteed in the code that I posted, because `someFunc` doesn't seem to know anything about `object`, but let's assume that this is indeed the case (because in my full program, it is). Am I safe then?

Comment: @goodvibration The problem is, from my experience, is that that assumption is true today, but won't be true in the future, and by then, the existence of the assumption in the code will be forgotten, and you get hard to find/debug bugs. There's really no reason to not create a new object here, the performance gain is negligible if at all.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`Object.keys`, like many other methods, returns an *Array* that you can iterate over. This *Array* is not "live" but a snapshot from the time of taking it (e.g. executing `Object.keys`). So yes, you're save to use it as intended.</strike>

There are very little examples of methods that return "live lists" instead of an *Array*; I guess you're having [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)s in mind, that you'll get when using *document.querySelectorAll*. This however not an *Array* but a *NodeList*.

However, there may be one pitfall I can see is: When a generated *newKey* already exists in the list of *oldKey*s (not the current one!). So you may or may not (depending on the position in the array) iterate over the already overwritten *new key*.

Comment: You've contradicted yourself. That last bit is exactly why the answer is that you're not safe to mutate the object as OP presented.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to change the key without creating a new Object.

```
for(key in obj){          
    Object.defineProperty(obj, `myNewName`, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key));
    delete obj[key];
}
```

Comment: I don't think that I'm creating a new object.

Comment: You're right @goodvibration. But the Answer with '.reduce' does.
I'm not saying that my answer is better, I just wanted to show a different approach :-)

Comment: OK, but you should probably change `"myNewName"` to `someFunc(key)` in your code.